# Get Name Destination Doesn't Return the Destination name

Tags: go, pdf

I was trying to copy named destinations from one PDF file to another. When calling `GetNamedDestinations` I am receiving `nil` despite pdfinfo shows multiple Named Destinations.

```
pdfinfo -dests named_dests.pdf
Page  Destination                 Name
1 [ XYZ   72  770 null      ] "h.fs7ss3djah12"
1 [ XYZ   72  718 null      ] "h.pxctvv5egybr"
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there any issue with the UniPDF library?

Comment: Which libraries are you using? You should extend your question or otherwise you risk being downvoted by quite a few votes...

Comment: @topskip - I have mentioned that I am using UniPDF library. The URL is https://cloud.unidoc.io